# the argument type 'map dynamic dynamic ' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'map string dynamic'

Tags: flutter, dart, arguments

I am using `dio` on my `ApiRepository` class. But there is an error showing on this line

```
 _dio.get(this.url, queryParameters: this.payload).then((response) {...
```

> the argument type 'map dynamic dynamic ' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'map string dynamic'

**Full Class**

```dart
class ApiRepository {

  final String url;
  
  final Map payload;

  ApiRepository(this.url, this.payload);

  final Dio _dio = Dio();

  void get({

    required Function() beforeSend,

    required Function(dynamic data) onSuccess,

    required Function(dynamic error) onError,

  }) {
   
 _dio.get(this.url, queryParameters: this.payload).then((response) {
     
 if (onSuccess != null) {

        onSuccess(response.data);

      }

    }).catchError((error) {

      if (onError != null) {

        onError(error);

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't try to bypass the system by pasting text, describe a little more about the efforts and errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

`queryParameters` requires `Map<String, dynamic>` but default `Map`is `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` .

Change `payload` map to
`final Map<String, dynamic> payload;`